# Efficient way of generating a random number of N (less than 64) bits with exactly M bits equal to one

Tags: algorithm-design, random-number-generator, implementation, randomness, pseudo-random-permutation

Would there be an efficient way to implement a function with the following signature:

```
unsigned long long int random_word(size_t n, size_t m)
```

that would generate a random machine word (64 bits here) such that exactly `m` bits over the `n` least significant ones at set to `1`. For example: `random_word(10, 3)` would generate a 64-bit random number such that 3 bits over the 10 LSBs are set to `1`. For a given `n` and `m` every possible output should have equal probability (uniform distribution of possible permutations).

If assembly bit twiddling hacks to do that are known, great, if not, I am looking for references and research directions.

Comment: If the percentage of samples that match the requirement from the full range of numbers isn't too small, then rejection sampling should work (only needs to be done on those n bits, the prefix can be randomized once and then you rejection sample the n bits)

Comment: Seems more like a programming challenge than crypto-related. Define "efficient":. Code size? Minimal number of uniformlly random bit used? Is that on average, for the first call, or..? Speed:  for the first call, for a million calls with the same n,m..? Is the time to generate uniform random bits counted in the performance?

Comment: Why do you need this in cryptography?

Comment: There's actually a second way that's likely more efficient (at least when m is far from n/2). Generate 64 minus n bits of random bits for the prefix, then simply generate a bitstring of m 1's and n-m 0's, and then you perform a randomized bitwise sort (with some random sort algorithms with a sufficiently small bias, using a unique random seed), and concatenate the two strings.

Comment: I don't get your sort. But if you just randomize the positions of the ones or zeros in the n LSB bits, and let the rest consist of random bits, then that should not introduce any bias, right?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes maybe it's just poorly described. I'm just trying to say what I think you expected, randomize the positions of the bits. He know exactly how many 1's and 0's he wants in the LSB, so he just needs to take that many of each and do a random sort on them. Bitwise = don't cluster them in bytes or anything like that when sorting. That should AFAICT retain the maximum amount of entropy which a bit sequence can contain under these constraints. Also a randomizing sort needs a seed for it's RNG

Comment: Ah, we are indeed in agreement then. I just was confused about the "random sort". I don't think that exists, we generally call that "random shuffle" rather than sort. Random sort contains a contradiction (random shuffle probably contains an unnecessary adjective though, shuffles are generally supposed to be random).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes then it's just a terminology question, I do mean shuffle

Comment: Drawing an error vector of a prescribed length and Hamming weight is one of the steps in the McEliece cryptosystem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you can simply split this into two problems:

1. create 64 - n random bits, call this R
2. shuffle n bits where m bits (at any location) are set to 1, call this P

Finally you can simply perform R | P (presuming big endian notation).

Shuffling lists of elements is an operation present in almost any language. If there is any inefficiency it would be in the shuffling algorithm (although Fisher-Yates is optimal, so you'd expect some form of that algorithm, possibly the inefficiency is getting values in a range...).

Comment: I'm thinking that you could also just generate a value x within of 0..n - i where i goes from 0 to m, where you set the x'th bit that is *not* set. That would be equivalent and easier to implement.

Comment: Actually, I've proven both experimentally and theoretically that the method in the above comment should not introduce bias (this is easy enough to prove).

Answer (score 1):

The problem for choosing $k$ bits from $64$ ultimately comes down to computing a uniformly random integer $r$ with $0 \leq r < \frac{64!}{k!(64-k)!}$ then decoding it to determine which bits.  The $k!$ in the denominator is annoying, but we can ignore it, because we can just allow our algorithm to have $k!$ random numbers that map to the same output (setting bit 0 then bit 4 is the same as setting bit 4 then bit 0).  Now we just have multiplying a decreasing sequence starting from $64$: with $k=4$ this equals $64 * 63 * 62 * 61$.

So for efficiency, you select a random number in $0 \le r_0 < 64$, then another $0 \le r_1 < 63$ ... through $0 \le r_{k-1} < 64-(k-1)$ each time using $r_n$ to select among the remaining unset bits.

I threw the following Python code together showing the idea, though it's not fast or anything:

```
# b = size of integer type
# n = number of set bits
# random_limited(x) is some function returning [0, x) sufficiently uniformly
def random_n_set_bits(b, n):
    assert b > 0
    assert n >= 0 and n <= b
    result = 0
    available = list(range(b))
    for i in range(n):
        index = random_limited(len(available))
        bit = available[index]
        available = available[:index] + available[index + 1:]
        result |= (1 << bit)
    return result
```